# Product Of Skew-Symmetric Matrix And Another Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a set of n points each(say p) of shape (3,) in numpy and a matrix(B) of shape (3,3).
I need to perform the product of the skew symmetric form of p and B.
I was trying to do the cross product of p and B as some resources online suggested product of skew symmetric form of a vector(p) with another matrix(B) is equivalent to cross product of the vector(p) with matrix(B).
I tried this:

```
p = np.array([2, 7, 4])
B = np.arange(9).reshape([3,3])
output = np.cross(p, B)
```

Result:

```
[[ 10  -4   2]
 [ 19   2 -13]
 [ 28   8 -28]]
```

But when I am trying to do it together for multiple points(10 below) I am getting an error:

```
ps = np.arange(30).reshape([10,3])
B = np.arange(9).reshape([3,3])
output = np.cross(ps, B)
```

Result:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "example.py", line 9, in
> <module>
>     output = np.cross(ps, B)   File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in cross   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line
> 1583, in cross
>     shape = broadcast(a[..., 0], b[..., 0]).shape ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Can you all please suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What does cross say about its arguments?

Comment: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: What shape do you expect the result to be?  `ps` has 10 'points', `B` has 3.  As inidcate by the error, it is trying to perform `broadcasting` on the leading dimensions of the arrays.  Do you know what `numpy` means by `broadcasting`?

Comment: I wanted you to look at the `np.cross` documentation.  I can read the error message.  That said, I see the `np.cross` is not overly explicit about how it handles 2d inputs, other than mentioning `broadcasting`.

Comment: `p` is a collection of `n` points in 3d space.  But what is `B` the (3,3) matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With (10,3) and (3,3) arrays:

```
In [621]: np.cross(ps,B)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-621-202aa85dbcf4>", line 1, in <module>
    np.cross(ps,B)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in cross
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1616, in cross
    shape = broadcast(a[..., 0], b[..., 0]).shape
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Adjusting the dimensions to (10,1,3) allows it to produce:

```
In [622]: np.cross(ps[:,None,:],B).shape
Out[622]: (10, 3, 3)
```

In effect it is doing an `outer` like product on the leading dimensions.  The `cross` part is on the trailing size 3 dimension.

But you may want to identify the sources that suggest using this.  The cross product between two vectors is another vector that is perpendicular to them (in a 3d space).  [622] is the cross product each of the `ps` set of vectors and each of the `B` set. I can't visual a context in which this operation makes sense.

---

Working from `skew-symmetric matrix` wiki article.

If I define two 1d arrays:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([1,2,3]); b = np.array([2,4,3])
```

Their `cross` product is:

```
In [2]: np.cross(a,b)
Out[2]: array([-6,  3,  0])
```

Define a function to make a skew symmetrix matrix:

```
In [3]: def mk_skew(a):
   ...:     return np.array([[0,-a[2],a[1]],[a[2],0,-a[0]],[-a[1],a[0],0]])
   ...: 
In [4]: A = mk_skew(a)
In [5]: A
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0, -3,  2],
       [ 3,  0, -1],
       [-2,  1,  0]])
In [6]: B = mk_skew(b)
```

The matching product is:

```
In [10]: A@b
Out[10]: array([-6,  3,  0])
In [11]: a@B
Out[11]: array([-6,  3,  0])
```

So I can imagine a collection of 'points', `p` as an array (n,3).  But I'm not sure what your `B` (3,3) matrix is supposed to be in this context?  It isn't skew-symmetric, and isn't a collection of 3 'points'.